# Deserialize simple string array

Tags: c#

I have a simple HTTPHandler pretending to be a Web Service 
(platform constraints, don't judge me)

I want to be able to create a string array in javascript, stringify it, and send it in a `REQUEST` header to be consumed as a set of parameters.

My issue is, most of the deserialization methods require you to create a named object and deserialize the whole object. I just want the simple string, man.

```
var ar = [];

ar.push("one");
ar.push("two");

var arStr = JSON.stringify(ar);

//$Ajax() bla bla bla
//sends out as "[\"one\",\"two\"]"
```

I'm sure there is a simple answer, but so far I can't find it.

**Addition**

Platform constraints also limit me from using 3rd part libraries. Needs to be straight .NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json is a string array/List. All you need is (using [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json))

```
List<string> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(jsonstring);
```

If you are using `JavaScriptSerializer`

```
var list = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<string>>(jsonstring);
```

**BTW:** *if you are using ajax, you don't need to stringify the object. Just post it as object. The library internally handles it, otherwise you may need double-deserialiazation at receiver end.*

Comment: I can't use outside libraries (Platform constraint as well). Can I use JSON.deserialize?

Answer (score 0):

`String.join(",", ar)` if you can make sure that your strings don't contain the separator character.